# Doxygen latex to PDF error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=2851623]

Tags: latex, doxygen, miktex

I am using Doxygen to document a large project.
I use Doxygen- 1.9.3 ,MikTeX - 22.3, MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.10 .
I have a Latex output and run the make.bat batch file to create a PDF file.
During the running of the batch file this error occurred:

[image]

Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: Would be good to mention in the question the real versions of doxygen and MikTeX you used and not latest as these are moving targets. Looks like your number of "string characters" is exhausted so you could try to increase it in your MikTeX configuration.

Comment: I have seen similar errors due to old graphic config files lying around. Can you show the full .log file?